# What is the proper name for this UX feature?

Tags: design-patterns, terminology, conventions

When I'm working in a programing IDE, I would call this feature "Code hinting", or "code completion".  However, in the context of form field, what would this feature be called?

[image]

The main reason I am asking, is so that I can search the net to find out some suggestions on how to make the feature.

The context here is that I have a free form, form to fill out.  However, some entries are more likely to be used, or re-used than others, and to help eliminate typos or looking up previous forms, I'd like to help those who will be filling out the form by giving them some "code hints".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Auto-suggest](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/27/tap-ahead-design-pattern-mobile-auto-suggest-on-steroids/) or term suggestion.

If what you are talking is the text that appears underneath a text field when you start typing.

You can also find it as [autocomplete](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Autocomplete).

Comment: Thanks.  I see from the search results that it's really popular with search fields! Should have thought of that.

Comment: Just FYI, AutoComplete was more useful for what I needed than Suggestion.

Comment: good to know, glad to help and glad to read the most accurate synonym for this situation.